# Where are the .DB3 file stored from SQLite Maestro

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to use sqlite database for my next project. I am currently learning some of SQLite Maestro basics. I found it easier to use. But when I created database, make tables and so on, where is the database .db3 file located ? I've tried searching whole C:\ for a .db3 files and I found it, but it's a shortcut and when I open the directory in which is found there's nothing in it. When first created the database I wasn't prompt to choose (e.g location, dir, folder, etc..) In SQLite Maestro's website I read that databases are usually stored in folder at the disk, so I am totally confused now. Where is my database ?

Comment: What is the output of `PRAGMA database_list;`?

Comment: The output is: 0|main| ... Like no database was created, but it exist inside Maestro !

Comment: I tried to create the database via sqlite3 shell "sqlite3 databasename.db3" and then create new database profile in Maestro and load up that database then execute my query for making tables and adding data. When I try to use the database I got error from the server saying "File opened that is not a database file. File is encrypted or it's not a database file".

Comment: What commands did you use in the shell? How exactly did you configure the DB profile?

Comment: I did not configure the DB profile. I just used the command "sqlite3 databasename.db3" and it creates an empty sqlite database. Then I opened it with Maestro and execute the query that makes the tables and adds the data. Once the server tries to use the database and outputs this error "File is encrypted or it's not a database file." it corrupts the database file and it can't be opened in Maestro or any other SQLite browser anymore. Huh? I've had a old .db3 file that worked well, but it was deleted and now it wont work, very strange...

Comment: SQLite is not a client/server database. What do you mean with "server"?

Comment: I have a C# game server that uses this sqlite database. I can provide the code for connecting to the database, etc if necessary.

Comment: Are you using the exact same file? Are you using encryption?

Comment: Yes, I am using the exact same file and I don't use encryption.